# Write values from Pandas DataFrame columns into tkinter TreeView/Table Columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tkinter, treeview

I want to write values from a dataframe into a tkinter treeview/Table, I am not able to do this.
my code:

```
#Setting up tkinter window.
root = Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(root)

#taking file input through a dialog box from the user.
file = filedialog.askopenfile(parent=root,mode='rb',title='Choose a xlsx file')

#readinf the excel file selected by the user and then creating a dataframe of that file.
xls = pd.read_excel(file)
df = pd.DataFrame(xls)

#taking all the columns heading in a variable"df_col".
df_col = df.columns.values

#all the column name are generated dynamically.
tree["columns"]=(df_col)
counter = len(df)

#generating for loop to create columns and give heading to them through df_col var.
for x in range(len(df_col)):
    tree.column(x, width=100 )
    tree.heading(x, text=df_col[x])
#generating for loop to print values of dataframe in treeview column. 
    for i in range(counter):
        tree.insert('', 0, values=(df[df_col[x]]][i]))
```

It is not printing the columns and showing the KeyError:0.

**Output Required:**
[image]

Comment: `df[df_col]` is the same as `df` and `df[0]` would be a column named `0` which doesn't exist.

Comment: @Goyo df_col is an array with df column names only, while df contains the whole dataframe with column names and values

Comment: i have made some update in the code

Comment: @Goyo this code prints all the results in a single column in tkinter treeview, while in my excel file there are 6 columns, im stuck about how to print the output in all 6 columns, btw thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument of tree.column() should be the column name, which you assigned with:

```
tree["columns"]=(df_col)
```

The problem is that you have named the columns using a string, but you are attempting to access them using integers in:

```
for x in range(len(df_col)):
    tree.column(x, width=100 )
    tree.heading(x, text=df_col[x])
```

Above, you are attempting to access tree.columns(0), instead of tree.columns('Company'), hence the key error.

Try instead:

```
for x in range(len(df_col)):
    tree.column(df_col[x], width=100)
    tree.heading(df_col[x], text=df_col[x])
```

Note that df_col is an ndarray, not a dataframe, which is why df_col[x] works correctly (df[x] would give a key error). This is because df.columns.values returns an ndarray. As a side note, it may be a bit confusing to name an ndarray df_col.

There are also a few issues with your insert. The second argument should correspond to the index of the entry you wish to address. One solution is then to use a row index as the second argument, followed by a row label as text="rowLabel", followed by a list of values for the row:

```
tree.insert('', i, text=rowLabels[i], values=df.iloc[i,:].tolist())
```

Where rowLabels should be defined as whatever you want to use in the first column of the table. I would suggest using an index column from the spreadsheet here, if possible. It could be defined by:

```
rowLabels = df.iloc[:,indexColumn].tolist()
```

or:

```
rowLabels = df.index.tolist()
```

The latter is viable if df has named indices defined by a column during the spreadsheet import. In the former, indexColumn is an int referring to a column number in df that contains unique identifiers.

The option values=df.iloc[i,:].tolist() converts all columns of the ith row into a list, and, since we have passed an index value (the second argument) that gets larger, the call will insert a new row every loop (from the python tkinter docs entry on Treeview --> insert: "if index is greater than or equal to the current number of children, it is inserted at the end").

Finally, I am not sure if you did not post the end of your code, but, in order for the tree to show up, you will also need to use pack, grid, etc.

```
tree.pack()
```

or

```
tree.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

References:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview

This helpful example makes a few of the steps clear:
https://knowpapa.com/ttk-treeview/

Answer (score 0):

As I was reading over your code. I noticed at the end line you have an extra bracket @:

```
df[df_col[x]]]
```

---

```
for i in range(counter):
    tree.insert('', 0, values=(df[df_col[x]]][i]))
```

I would assume that would explain the KeyError.